# email form adding a phone number

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I have this form on my contact page:

```
    <?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail("contact@*****.com", $name, 
  $message, "From:" . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form. <br><br>We will get back to you within 48 hours.";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  {
  echo "<br><form method='post' action='enquiry.php' align='center'>
  <strong>Name: </strong><input class='textbox' name='name' type='text'><br><br>
  <strong>Email: </strong><input class='textbox' name='email' type='text'><br><br>
  <strong>Phone: </strong><input class='textbox' name='phone' type='text'><br><br>
  <strong>Message: </strong><br>
  <textarea class='textbox' name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br>
  <input type='submit'><br><br>
  </form>";
  }
?>
```

which sends me an email when someone submits the form.

but when I try to add `$phone` to my email code. it fails to send the mail to me.

please can someone advise me on where I can add this? thank you.

Comment: Make sure php errors are turn on. Also post how you adding `$phone` in your code ?

Comment: show two different code ,for two different case

Comment: Where you have added your phone number ($phone)previously? Can you please explain little bit. your question is not that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
$message = $_REQUEST['message'].$phone;
```

This will appened the mobile number with your message.

Answer (score 1):

So what's the problem, append the number to $message before sending it.

```
$message .= $phone;
```

Comment: sorry im not following you. where do i put that code? im new to php.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email'])) //if "email" is filled out, send email
{
      //send email
      $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
      $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
      $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
      $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

      $message_text = $message." Phone no:".$phone; // combine here $message and $phone to $message_text

      mail("contact@*****.com", $name, $message_text, "From:" . $email); // now use $message_text here to send mail
      echo "Thank you for using our mail form. <br><br>We will get back to you within 48 hours.";
}
else //if "email" is not filled out, display the form
{
      echo "<br><form method='post' action='enquiry.php' align='center'>
      <strong>Name: </strong><input class='textbox' name='name' type='text'><br><br>
      <strong>Email: </strong><input class='textbox' name='email' type='text'><br><br>
      <strong>Phone: </strong><input class='textbox' name='phone' type='text'><br><br>
      <strong>Message: </strong><br>
      <textarea class='textbox' name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
      </textarea><br>
      <input type='submit'><br><br>
      </form>";
 }
?>
```